how do i connect html and php?
I'm working on creating a signup page for a webpage and have the following HTML code in signup.html:
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="section">
            <div class="heading">
                <h1>Signup</h1>
            </div>
            <form action="/php/signup.php" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="button">Signup</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

Initially, I'm attempting to check if my HTML is properly connected to PHP, but it doesn't seem to be working.
My file structure is organized as follows:
file structure of my code
In signup.php, I'm attempting to display the form data from the browser after submission using the following code:
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>

However, I encounter the following error:
"This page isn’t working. If the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 405."
Additionally, in the browser console, I see the message: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()".
What could be causing this issue and how can I resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I was doing this from a video but I got error doing so.
Also not writing anything on php does the same error.

Sounds like you're using something like LiveServer to serve your app. This won't work with PHP out-of-the-box. You'll need a PHP server

@Phil myphpserver is runnning and I am using XAMPP. how do I run my HTML with PHP server

What URL are you opening in your browser?

@Phil the problem is solved...apparently i was using live server to run my HTML code.
